# how to get the reference for the number part of the atom/ref/future

Tags: clojure

At the clojure repl, there is a unique number that pops up for any IDeref object

```
user=> (def a (atom 1))
#'user/a
user=> a
#<Atom@2e1c6600: 1>
```

where is this number - `2e1c6600`- stored  and how do we grab this number from `a`?

Comment: That's an implementation detail and you should not be worried about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the hex representation of the hashCode of the underlying Java Object. If you absolutely need it, you can get it using `(Integer/toHexString (.hashCode a))`

```
user=> (def a (atom 1))
#'user/a
user=> a
#<Atom@56092666: 1>  
user=> (Integer/toHexString (.hashCode a))
"56092666"
```

Comment: Or `System/idenntityHashCode`, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 1):

that is the java object id of the atom. Its not intended to be used except to aid in debugging. if you really want it you can call str on the atom then chop it out of the string and feed it to Integer/parseInt